# Interpreting regression output: stock index percentage vs basis point change

Tags: terminology, stock, calculation

I'm trying to understand how to interpret a regression output when the dependent variable is weekly stock market return. I have calculated the return variable as the weekly percentage change in the S&P500 price index.

The way I interpret a coefficient of 0.85 is that a one unit increase in X is associated with an increase of   0.85 *percentage points* in weekly returns. To illustrate, if the weekly return had been 4%, now it would be 4.85%.

Is this the correct way to interpret the coefficient of 0.85?

Most importantly, how can I calculate what *basis point* change this percentage change corresponds to? How should I go about figuring out the change in annual returns?

Grateful for any insights!